# How to set the background color of the layout constant after it has been changed programmatically?

Tags: android

Such as if we change the background color by clicking the button and the code to change background color is:

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03a9f4"));
```

It will change the background to blue. But it will turn to default white after switching the activities or closing the activities. I want the color to be constant after changing it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last color you used in your designated View (let's call it `view`) and store it in `SharedPreferences` in `onPause()`:

```
int lastColor = ((PaintDrawable) view.getBackground()).getPaint().getColor();
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity);
pref.edit().putInt("last_color", lastColor).commit();
```

Then restore the color in `onResume()`:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity);
int lastColor = pref.getInt("last_color",0);
view.setBackgroundColor(lastColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Persist the color (e.g. in `SharedPreferences`) and then set it everytime your `View` is created.